# How do I bootstrap my EC2 webserver to connect to the Chef GUI page? Where it says nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, centos7, configuration-management

I'm trying to get my CentOS 7 EC2 instance to show under here...?
https://api.chef.io/organizations/rp_training_org/nodes

I have an CentOS 7 EC2 instance with ChefDK installed and I need to get it connected to the Chef GUI page...I'm somewhat a newbie to Chef, so is that GUI page called the Chef Server?

It would be a "GREAT" help if you could send me the command line instructions as to how to do it....like a full example of what the command would like...? I'm clueless at this point, I'm doing the below, but it's asking me for a password....EC2 servers don't have passwords...

knife bootstrap ec2-18-212-179-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo --identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa --node-name Main Server

Answer (score 0):

You would generally use `knife bootstrap` but there are many options depending on the specifics of your infrastructure. You can find our introductory tutorials at https://learn.chef.io/.

Comment: When I do this it's asking me for a password...."knife bootstrap ec2-18-212-179-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo --identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa --node-name Main Server" I don't know what to do...?

Comment: You need to use the SSH key corresponding to how you launched the EC2 instance.